# Does player level affect matchmaking?

Tags: overwatch

**tl;dr**: Does player level affect matchmaking or is it based on stats?

Recently, matchmaking in Overwatch has been extremely weird.

A few times I've gotten games with huge player level gaps. Recently, I played a match where we had a level 6 and a level 97 on our team.

However, what makes me believe that level does matter is that when I hit level 31 I started getting matched with higher level players. Whereas before I was consistently getting matched with level 2-12 players.

What seems to be the case now is that matchmaking is based on player stats but that still does not explain the huge level differences. A 50% win rate on a level 6 player doesn't compare with a 50% win rate for a level 97 player, at least in my opinion.

Most of the time, I get players in the 30-50 level range, but it's not entirely consistent and it could still mean that players with that amount of play time would have similar statistics.

So does my level affect the players I would be matched with or is it based on something different, specifically player stats? Also, what could cause the huge differences in player levels if there is a connection between time played/levels earned and matchmaking?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to [Jeff Kaplan](http://us.battle.net/forums/en/overwatch/topic/20744524460),

> We match based on skill, ping and group size.

So, level shouldn't matter. To further break down what each of those categories are, this post [here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/878359-overwatch/73807095) describes what the matchmaking system looks for when trying to balance teams.

> "Skill" in this context refers to two things: your win rate and your MMR. Your win rate is calculated by taking the number of games you've won and dividing that by the total number of games you've played. Your MMR is an invisible number that goes up when you win and down when you lose and is supposed to represent how good you are at the game. Your MMR has to start somewhere, and while your account is new it will fluctuate wildly with each game played as the system is trying to figure out what number best represents your skill based on your average. As you continue to play games, the system becomes more confident in your MMR and the fluctuating decreases. A good matchmaking system will pair up players with similar confident MMR scores, in theory creating even games every time.
>
> "Ping" is a number, measured in milliseconds (0.001 of a second), that
> represents how long it takes your console to send information to the
> host or server and receive a response back from the server. High ping
> is a direct cause of things such as shots not registering, people
> teleporting around, getting kills by shooting thin air, and other
> issues that people generally associate with lag. Thus, a low-ping
> environment is preferable.
>
> "Group size", in theory, should refer to pairing up premade teams of
> similar size against each other, mitigating the inherent advantage of
> premades (communication, consistent roles, confidence in the skill of
> your teammates, etc.) by giving that advantage to both teams. Bigger
> premade should = bigger advantage, thus the need for groups of similar
> size on each team.

Though, it should be noted, the longer you are searching for matches, the looser the constraints will become in attempt to get you into a game.

Comment: I play with two groups, either with my 13-year-old or with ~5 coworkers.  From what I have observed, the people I end up playing against with my 13-year-old are far more incompetent at the game then those I end up playing against with my coworkers.

Comment: @StevenBurnap the 13 year old probably has a lower mmr which brings your groups average mmr down.

Comment: Still, the whole "skill based on W/L ratio" thing in a team-based game kind of screws things up for people who play a lot in Quick Play games. Is there really no system in place to track you performance in a game, without taking the team as a whole as a factor? Because it does remind me of a certain hellish ELO place...

Comment: @DGarvanski There is such a system. It's your MMR. Additionally, it may be a team-based game, but your W/L ratio will reflect upon how much you're able to contribute to the win.

Comment: @DCShannon You'd think that, but for payers who play a lot of certain roles (support especially) no matter how good you are things will turn on how capable the rest of your team is.  No support can save players determined to go all Leroy Jenkins, and if your team is just going to play badly and get themselves killed, or won't play to whatever your healing mechanism is, or won't try to push through when you use Transcendence, nothing you do is going to help.

Comment: @NerdyCanuck You're talking about a single game. If you're good at support, your teams will tend to win. If you're bad at it, they will tend to lose, the performance of a particular team in a particular game not withstanding.

Comment: Looking at my own statistics, my win/lose ration varies dramatically by character, which implies that my individual contribution does matter as victory is more likely when I pick a character I am good at vs. a character I am bad at.

Comment: @DCShannon: *In the long run* this is true, but A) there will be a lot of statistical noise and B) players may be better at one class than another, and prefer one class to another (not necessarily the same classes, of course), and these confounding variables must be corrected for when calculating the MMR (fortunately, Blizzard not only has enough information to actually make those corrections, but said information is even exposed in the player-visible statistics screen).

Comment: @DCShannon: I understand you're suggesting that it would normalize, but I think k that'sissing a negative feedback loop that can occur, as getting placed into a poor team acts to reduce MMR and win rate, which increases the odds of a poor team, which acts to reduce MMR and win rate, and so on.  Given all the more directly relevant performance stats they track, there's frankly no excuse to be using a second or third degree indicator like that.

Comment: When they said 'skill', I instantly thought of the Fire meter. But I guess being good at the game and having low 'skill' due to bad teammates is a win-win.

Comment: @NerdyCanuck You've got a point with the negative feedback loop to some extent, but you're not considering the other team. If you're being matched with bad teammates, you're also being matched with bad opponents. If you're not being matched with these people because you're bad, but because your past teammates have been bad, then at some point you'll be enough better than the other team to turn the tide. There are some other stats that are more individual, sure, but nothing is so direct at determining whether you can win games than checking if you've won games.

Comment: @DCShannon: I'd really argue that win rate is a lot less direct than other metrics Blizzard measures.  It wouldn't be that difficult, actually, to create a player rating that put together contribution in role, contribution out of role, and versatility; this would create a much more effective means of judging performance.   They track some really fine grain information that could be used to do a lot. I almost wonder if they're saving such a system for the Competitive mode.