# Strategic Incurring of the Leaver Penalty in Overwatch to boost the W/L rate

Tags: overwatch

Assume someone is really intent on having a very good win/loss rate.

There is a 75% exp penalty for frequent leavers, which means frequent leavers will level up significantly slower.

Matchmaking is at least partly (?) based on level.

Considering all of the above, would it be possible (and prudent) for someone who seeks to maximize their W/L ratio to quit every very likely lost game before the end, in order to be matched with newer players for longer?

Comment: Please don't. There's nothing worse than someone disconnecting from your team just because they thought it was gg. It's not gg until it's gg.

Comment: @Unionhawk they live in loop of self-fulfilling prophecy, with such behavior predicted loses indeed have higher chance to occur.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, [its not based on Level](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/270067/does-player-level-affect-matchmaking). Level is just a number representing the amount of time you've put into the game.

Secondly, if you're not happy with your team you can leave when the match is over and restart the queue to get a fresh batch of teammates and enemies.

I personally don't see a reason to handicap your loot box receiving time, it won't help you get any better or worse players for your or your enemy's teams.

Also, I watched a video recently (can't find it though) where the narrator suggests that the game will strive for 50/50 W/L ratio. The more you win the tougher opponents you'll get. The more you lose the easier it will be on you. It was a speculation only, but it made sense.

Comment: `the game will strive for 50/50 W/L ratio.` Sort of, but not quite. The game strives for every game to be equal. That means its evaluation of your skill level will increase if you win a lot and you will face harder opponents. But the game won't punish you for a winning streak by giving you a really hard game, just a slightly harder one each time you win.

Comment: @Decency anecdotally, I've experienced situations like the contrast between easy/hard matches. Had an 8 win-streak (all relatively close games), then got rematched against a different team that didn't even let us leave spawn for the whole duration of the map.

Comment: I'm level 40 atm. Sometimes, I'm in a game where I could 1v6 the enemy team on mercy. Sometimes however, our team doesn't get to leave spawn until the match is over.

Comment: I really want to see a Mercy with 5 gold medals now :P

Answer (score 3):

If you quit a game before the end of the match, it is chalked as a loss and goes against your matches played vs matches completed ratio. So if you're seeking to maximize your W/L rate, the simplest answer would be to avoid losing by actually winning, rather than jumping ship.

As an aside to that, having a higher win rate wouldn't consistently match you against newer players (who have wildly swinging W/L ratios as each individual match has more impact for a newer player compared to one with 200+ games under their belt).

Comment: But more recent matches will count for more than those played while still being a noob. Especially as you gain in skill/try out new heros

Comment: @ratchetfreak define 'recent matches will count for more'. Wins and losses are not weighted by how much game time preceeded them, and so the recent matches will add the same value to your W/L as they did when you just started. The difference is relative (+1 win out of 10 total matches is a greater percentage than +1 win out of 100 total matches), which is why you won't be consistently matched against newer players- their W/L will seesaw like crazy at the start of their OW career.

Comment: I'm talking about your MMR which is used to match you up against players of equal skill. Which will change depending on wins/losses and who you played with/against.

Comment: @ratchetfreak Oh I see. Yeah, MMR will become more affected per game as you gain playtime but the W/L ratio is the inverse of that.